# HttpHandler receiving 404 and 500 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

Im running a website on WindowsServer 2008 R2, and IIS 6.1 sp1

I created an empty ASP.NET 4.0 web application, and added an http handler to it. The job of the handler will be to redirect incoming calls to other sites based on a tokenid passed in the querystring (from a federated single sign on provider).

To test the connection, I am just parsing the token into a Dictionary and writing the information to the context.Response.

The handler works on my machine, but when I deploy it, I get 500 and 403 errors.
I get 500 errors when I make the application pool ASP.NET 4.0 Integrated, I get 404 errors when make the application pool ASP.NET 4.0 Classic

If I add a test.htm to the directory, I can access the test.htm and see its contents, but I would be expecting to see the output from the handler, so it makes me think it cant find the handler.

Here is the web.config followed by the code

```
   <configuration>
       <system.web>
          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />

          <httpHandlers>
             <add verb="*" path="*"
                type="RedirectSite.RedirectHttpHandler, RedirectSite, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" />
          </httpHandlers>        
       </system.web>        
    <configuration>

        public class RedirectHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
            {

                public RedirectHttpHandler()
                { }

                public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
                {

                    // check for tokenid in querystring
                    string tokenid = context.Request.Params["tokenid"];
                    string agentid = context.Request.Params["agentid"];

                    Dictionary<string,string> tokenItems = TokenParser.Parse(tokenid, agentid);

                    context.Response.Clear();

                    context.Response.Write("<b>Token Information</b><br/><br/>");

                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item  in tokenItems)
                    {
                        context.Response.Write(String.Format("{0} : {1}<br/>",item.Key,item.Value));
                    }

               }
                public bool IsReusable { get; private set; }
            }
```

Comment: Just a shot in the sky but, should your assemply be `StrongNamed`/`Signed`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the ISAPI/CGI settings for the site were preventing 4.0 - once enabled, the site worked